# How to set same method on Multiple togglebuttons

Tags: android

I have set setOnCheckedChangeListener method to a first togglebutton , I want to set all togglebuttons with the same method . Can someone help me:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ToggleButton toggleButton;
private ToggleButton toggleButton2;
private ToggleButton toggleButton3;
private ToggleButton toggleButton4;
private ToggleButton toggleButton5;
private ToggleButton toggleButton6;
private ToggleButton toggleButton7;
private TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                textView.setText("1");
            } else
                textView.setText("0");
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: you need to check all toggle once first one is selected right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more way to do is

```
public class MainActivity  extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
toggleButton2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
toggleButton3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this); //and all others
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            textView.setText("1");
        } else
            textView.setText("0");
    }
    }
}
```

Advantage by using interface is later on if you want to change behavior of single toggleButton, you can check it's ID and use different task in override method like follows,

```
public class MainActivity  extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        switch (buttonView.getId()){
            case R.id.b1 : someMethod1(); break;
            case R.id.b2 : someMethod2(); break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a single listener and assgn it to the toggle buttons

```
private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChange = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(textView != null) {
           if (isChecked) {
               textView.setText("1");
           } else  {
               textView.setText("0");
           }
        }
    }
});
```

and in onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
  textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

  toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChange);
  toggleButton2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChange);
  ...............
  ..............
```

Answer (score 0):

First: Use a collection of views
Then: build a function with the same event functionality
And then: Use them both

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ToggleButton[] toggleButtons;

private TextView textView;

private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListene toggleButtonChcekcedEvent()
{
   new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                textView.setText("1");
            } else
                textView.setText("0");
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toggleButtons = new ToggleButton[]
    {
        (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton),
        (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2),
        // please continue to initialize the rest here
    }

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    for (ToggleButton button : toggleButtons)
    {
         button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleButtonChcekcedEvent());
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) in your application you can handle your click listener like this.

> ButterKnife help you to manage your bindView and clickManager and ...

```
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'


    @OnClick({R.id.toggleButton1,
        R.id.toggleButton2, 
        R.id.toggleButton3})
     public void clickListener(View view) {   
      switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.toggleButton1:
        case R.id.toggleButton2:
        case R.id.toggleButton3:
          //do something here
          break;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to define the handler in xml like this:

```
<ToggleButton 
  ...
  ...
  android:onClick="onToggleClicked"/>
```

Then in your Activity:

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if (on) {
       // Turn on things
    } else {
      // Turn off things
    }
}
```

This is much DRY and easier to maintain.